# Multiple clients require different JAXB annotations

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a class that may be consumed by multiple clients (i.e a GUI, an external system etc).

```
@XmlRootElement
class A {
    String field = "Hello World";

    public String getField() {
       return field;
    }
}
```

For one client I don't want the resulting XML to include all of the details in the class so I mark the details I want to hide with XmlTransient.

```
@XmlRootElement
class A {
    String field = "Hello World";

    @XmlTransient
    public String getField() {
       return field;
    }
}
```

The trouble is that the other client needs to see that data, and now it's hidden.

How do I go about fulfilling a requirement where I have two clients who want almost the same data? I've made this work by extending A and annotating appropriately to meet the needs of each client:

```
@XmlRootElement
class B extends A {
    @XmlTransient
    public String getField() {
       return super.getField();
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
class C extends A {
    public String getField() {
       return super.getField();
    }
}
```

This works but seems cumbersome. Are there any other ways of doing this? I realise that in the instance I have shown I could use an XmlJavaAdapter but in my real-life code the data I am referring to could be part of a composite object and the XmlJavaAdapter seems inappropriate.

Hope this all makes sense!

Comment: Standard JAXB isn't the right tool for this, you need to externalise your mapping descriptors. Proprietary extensions such as MOXy might be able to do it, though.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

As mentioned by [**@skaffman**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman), you can use MOXy extensions to accomplish this use case.  MOXy offers the ability to represent the mapping metadata as XML.  This means that you can provide one mapping as annotations, plus additional mappings as XML.

Below is a link to an example where a single object model is mapped to the results of the Google and Yahoo weather services:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

The code that corresponds to this example is also available on GitHub:

- https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110908

Answer (score 0):

I guess MOXy is not free (correct me if I am wrong please).

My free solution is to use an extra "version" field in the JAXB object to distinguish multiple versions of bindings. Usually, I use enum as its type, i.e., 
    enum Version {V1, V2, ...};

So for the original example, I define the getField() method as

```
@XmlElement
public String getField() {
    if (version == Version.V1) {
        return field;
    } else if (version == Version.V2) {
        return null; // hidden
    }

}
```

For client 1, I will set the version value to Version.V1, and then marshall the Java object; same for client 2, I will change the version value to Version.v2 before marshalling.