# Can you have multiple sets of JAXB annotations to marshal/unmarshal to different XML?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

We have some entities with JAXB annotations so that we can unmarshal some 'incoming' XML to pojo. We now need to marshal the pojos to XML but to a different format than the incoming xml. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple clients require different JAXB annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838286/multiple-clients-require-different-jaxb-annotations)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use an extra "version" field in the JAXB object to distinguish multiple versions of bindings. Usually, I use enum as its type, i.e., 
    enum Version {V1, V2, ...};

So for a specific XML element field, I define the getField() method as

```
@XmlElement
public String getField() {
    if (version == Version.V1) {
        return field;
    } else if (version == Version.V2) {
        return null; // hidden
    }

}
```

Before marshalling, one just needs to set the version value to the desired enum value, and JAXB will take care of the rest.